# Error when commenting on a Dexterity object

Tags: plone, dexterity

I created a content type that is not folderish and allows discussion. The forms to add comments is displayed but when post a comment I got the next error:

```
2013-03-09 22:24:32 ERROR root Exception while rendering an error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.19-py2.6.egg/OFS/SimpleItem.py", line 242, in raise_standardErrorMessage
    v = s(**kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.2.7-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFCore/FSPythonScript.py", line 127, in __call__
    return Script.__call__(self, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.19-py2.6.egg/Shared/DC/Scripts/Bindings.py", line 322, in __call__
    return self._bindAndExec(args, kw, None)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.19-py2.6.egg/Shared/DC/Scripts/Bindings.py", line 359, in _bindAndExec
    return self._exec(bound_data, args, kw)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/Products.PythonScripts-2.13.2-py2.6.egg/Products/PythonScripts/PythonScript.py", line 344, in _exec
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "Script (Python)", line 34, in standard_error_message
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.19-py2.6.egg/Shared/DC/Scripts/Bindings.py", line 322, in __call__
    return self._bindAndExec(args, kw, None)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.19-py2.6.egg/Shared/DC/Scripts/Bindings.py", line 359, in _bindAndExec
    return self._exec(bound_data, args, kw)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.2.7-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFCore/FSPageTemplate.py", line 237, in _exec
    result = self.pt_render(extra_context=bound_names)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.2.7-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFCore/FSPageTemplate.py", line 177, in pt_render
    self, source, extra_context
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.19-py2.6.egg/Products/PageTemplates/PageTemplate.py", line 79, in pt_render
    showtal=showtal)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.pagetemplate-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/pagetemplate/pagetemplate.py", line 113, in pt_render
    strictinsert=0, sourceAnnotations=sourceAnnotations)()
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 271, in __call__
    self.interpret(self.program)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
    handlers[opcode](self, args)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 888, in do_useMacro
    self.interpret(macro)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
    handlers[opcode](self, args)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 533, in do_optTag_tal
    self.do_optTag(stuff)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 518, in do_optTag
    return self.no_tag(start, program)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 513, in no_tag
    self.interpret(program)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
    handlers[opcode](self, args)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 852, in do_condition
    self.interpret(block)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
    handlers[opcode](self, args)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 742, in do_insertStructure_tal
    structure = self.engine.evaluateStructure(expr)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.19-py2.6.egg/Products/PageTemplates/Expressions.py", line 218, in evaluateStructure
    text = super(ZopeContext, self).evaluateStructure(expr)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.tales-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/tales/tales.py", line 696, in evaluate
    return expression(self)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.contentprovider-3.7.2-py2.6.egg/zope/contentprovider/tales.py", line 77, in __call__
    provider.update()
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.viewlet-3.7.2-py2.6.egg/zope/viewlet/manager.py", line 112, in update
    self._updateViewlets()
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.viewlet-3.7.2-py2.6.egg/zope/viewlet/manager.py", line 118, in _updateViewlets
    viewlet.update()
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/plone.app.discussion-2.1.9-py2.6.egg/plone/app/discussion/browser/comments.py", line 263, in update
    self.form.update()
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/plone.z3cform-0.7.8-py2.6.egg/plone/z3cform/fieldsets/extensible.py", line 59, in update
    super(ExtensibleForm, self).update()
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/plone.z3cform-0.7.8-py2.6.egg/plone/z3cform/patch.py", line 30, in GroupForm_update
    _original_GroupForm_update(self)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/z3c.form-2.5.1-py2.6.egg/z3c/form/group.py", line 138, in update
    self.actions.execute()
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/z3c.form-2.5.1-py2.6.egg/z3c/form/action.py", line 99, in execute
    result = handler()
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/z3c.form-2.5.1-py2.6.egg/z3c/form/button.py", line 315, in __call__
    return handler(self.form, self.action)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/z3c.form-2.5.1-py2.6.egg/z3c/form/button.py", line 170, in __call__
    return self.func(form, action)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/plone.app.discussion-2.1.9-py2.6.egg/plone/app/discussion/browser/comments.py", line 232, in handleComment
    comment_review_state = workflowTool.getInfoFor(comment, 'review_state')
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.2.7-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFCore/WorkflowTool.py", line 263, in getInfoFor
    raise WorkflowException(msg)
WorkflowException: No workflow provides '${name}' information.
```

I put the code [here](https://github.com/danielhz/degu.forum/tree/540d34af26670925f181fdbf5b0503d451c6afc6). To reproduce the error run `setupenv.sh` and then `bin/instance fg`. Then go to the browser and create a new site using `degu.forum`. Create a forum folder with a forum inside and put a forum thread into. Then try to post comments on the forum thread.

Comment: How did you install the comments add-on? The workflow definition for comments appears to be missing.

Comment: In the type xml I set `<property name="allow_discussion">True</property>` and in the site setup I set "Globally enable comments" on.

Comment: This looks like the [`plone.app.discussion`](http://plone.org/products/plone.app.discussion) is not yet set up properly.

Comment: I'm using Plone 4.2 so I suppose I don't need to add `plone.app.discussion` to the eggs in `buildout.cfg`.

Comment: Code is very small. I put it [here](https://github.com/danielhz/degu.forum/tree/540d34af26670925f181fdbf5b0503d451c6afc6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allthough Martijn's comment is already the solution and the error-message is quite clear, I'll post it as an answer:

Go to the workflow-tool and check, if any workflow is assigned to discussions, at all.

Most likely it isn't. Assign one, f.e. the 'one_state_workflow' as conveniently used for comments, and update the security-settings.